# Efficient Multi dimenstion Mutable Scala Array

Tags: arrays, scala, out-of-memory

Is there memory efficient Scala multi dimension array such as in Java?

I'm trying to solve [Hackerrank](https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/stockmax) problem with strict memory constraints: 256mb. My solution breaks with out of memory error while creating 2D array with (39384,39384) elements:

```
Array.ofDim[Long](39384,39384)
```

The same happens in scala console.

```
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
        at scala.reflect.ManifestFactory$$anon$9.newArray(Manifest.scala:115)
        at scala.reflect.ManifestFactory$$anon$9.newArray(Manifest.scala:113)
        at scala.Array$.ofDim(Array.scala:222)
        at Solution$.solve(Solution.scala:4)
        at Solution$$anonfun$main$1.apply$mcVI$sp(Solution.scala:41)
        at scala.collection.immutable.Range.foreach$mVc$sp(Range.scala:160)
        at Solution$.main(Solution.scala:37)
        at Solution.main(Solution.scala)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
        at scala.reflect.internal.util.ScalaClassLoader$$anonfun$run$1.apply(ScalaClassLoader.scala:68)
        at scala.reflect.internal.util.ScalaClassLoader$class.asContext(ScalaClassLoader.scala:31)
        at scala.reflect.internal.util.ScalaClassLoader$URLClassLoader.asContext(ScalaClassLoader.scala:99)
        at scala.reflect.internal.util.ScalaClassLoader$class.run(ScalaClassLoader.scala:68)
        at scala.reflect.internal.util.ScalaClassLoader$URLClassLoader.run(ScalaClassLoader.scala:99)
        at scala.tools.nsc.CommonRunner$class.run(ObjectRunner.scala:22)
        at scala.tools.nsc.ObjectRunner$.run(ObjectRunner.scala:39)
        at scala.tools.nsc.CommonRunner$class.runAndCatch(ObjectRunner.scala:29)
        at scala.tools.nsc.ObjectRunner$.runAndCatch(ObjectRunner.scala:39)
        at scala.tools.nsc.MainGenericRunner.runTarget$1(MainGenericRunner.scala:72)
        at scala.tools.nsc.MainGenericRunner.process(MainGenericRunner.scala:94)
        at scala.tools.nsc.MainGenericRunner$.main(MainGenericRunner.scala:103)
        at scala.tools.nsc.MainGenericRunner.main(MainGenericRunner.scala)
```

Comment: Is your multidimensional array going to be sparse?  If not, then there is no way to make your multi-dim array "more efficient" since all of those values need to be stored.  You could use memory mapped files, or if your machine has the RAM for it you could just expand the max memory of the JVM at startup.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Array.ofDim[Long](39384,39384)` creates array with size `39384 * 39384 * Long = 1551099456 * 8 = 11 Gb` which is obviously more than `256 Mb`. Just try less dimensions to see how it works:

```
scala> Array.ofDim[Long](3,3)
res10: Array[Array[Long]] = Array(Array(0, 0, 0), Array(0, 0, 0), Array(0, 0, 0))
```

If you need some coordinates processing for large geometric space - you may just create `Map[Point, Long]` of ponts, like `Map(Point(39382, 9000) -> 5L, Point(1,0) -> 9L)` .

If you actually just need two arrays (each 39384 sized) - then just create two arrays `Array.ofDim[Long](39384,2)`

P.S. If your algorithm is scalable you may also use multiple nodes of Apache Spark for calculations.

Comment: It is impossible to fit such array in JVM heap. I need to choose different algorithm for this problem.